# Issue with Hive streaming and Azure Data Lake Store

Tags: java, azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I am writing a Play2 Java web application to ingest data to HDInsight interactive query using the Hive Streaming API(https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Streaming+Data+Ingest). Hive data is stored on Azure Data Lake Store.

I loosely based myself on https://github.com/mradamlacey/hive-streaming-azure-hdinsight/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cbre/eim/HiveStreamingExample.java.

When I run the code on one of my headnodes I receive the following error:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[StreamingIOFailure: Failed creating RecordUpdaterS for adl://home/hive/warehouse/data/ingest_date=2018-05-07 txnIds[486,495]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:251)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:182)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:343)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:341)
        at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:414)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    Caused by: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.StreamingIOFailure: Failed creating RecordUpdaterS for adl://home/hive/warehouse/data/ingest_date=2018-05-07 txnIds[486,495]
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.AbstractRecordWriter.newBatch(AbstractRecordWriter.java:166)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.StrictJsonWriter.newBatch(StrictJsonWriter.java:41)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.<init>(HiveEndPoint.java:559)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.<init>(HiveEndPoint.java:512)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.fetchTransactionBatchImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:397)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.fetchTransactionBatch(HiveEndPoint.java:377)
        at hive.HiveRepository.createMany(HiveRepository.java:76)
        at controllers.HiveController.create(HiveController.java:40)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(Routes.scala:70)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:137)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: adl
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2651)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRecordUpdater.<init>(OrcRecordUpdater.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat.getRecordUpdater(OrcOutputFormat.java:292)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.AbstractRecordWriter.createRecordUpdater(AbstractRecordWriter.java:226)
```

I raised the question on the [Microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5d07eada-9f4d-4089-a923-895a056df040/hive-streaming-to-hdinsight-with-azure-data-lake-storage?forum=hdinsight) as well and on the [Hive jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-19475).

I can confirm that the jars described [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure-datalake/index.html) are present in the classpath:

```
com.microsoft.azure.azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.2.5.jar
org.apache.hadoop.hadoop-azure-datalake-3.1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

> No FileSystem for scheme

You get this error when [the filesystem is not configured](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure-datalake/index.html#Configuring_Credentials_and_FileSystem) which probably needs to be done at both the HiveServer and your local client's core-site.xml files

Just because the JARs exist doesn't mean they are loaded onto the classpath and configured to read from your Azure account

Comment: And try some portion of these commands from your local client, or the Hive server to see what happens. **Outside** of a Hive shell... In other words, it's a Hadoop configuration problem, not Hive https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure-datalake/index.html#Accessing_adl_URLs

Comment: I can access the data lake store without anny issues with bin/hadoop fs, so I assume this is correctly configured.

Comment: What makes you think the jars are not on the classpath? How can I double check?

Comment: `hadoop classpath` would be that command... But you need to inspect your core site file to verify that the adls filesystem is configured.

Comment: I assume this is correctly configured if can access it with hadoop fs?

Comment: On what machine? The HiveServer or something else? Each Hadoop client has its own configuration files